# Capitalize first letter of each word in java

Tags: java

So far after searching the web I can only get the first word to be capitalized. 
"Wonder Woman" and "The Avengers" only get the first letter capitalized in the 1st word and not the 2nd. 
I'm basically looking for that "java trick" to do the trick and not use a different class like WordUtilize or what ever it is.

Here's my code:

```
public class Movie extends Shows{ 

    private static String title;
    private static HashSet<String> _Movie;
    private static float time;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getTitle(); 
    }

    public static void getTitle() {
        theMovies();
        Scanner _title = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which movie would you like to see?");
        title = _title.nextLine();

        title = title.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + title.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        _title.close();
        System.out.println("You entered " + title + " movie");

        if(_Movie.contains(title)) {
            System.out.println(title);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, we only have Batman, Superman, Wonder Woman, and The Avengers");
        }
    }

    public static void theMovies() {
        _Movie = new HashSet<>();
        _Movie.add("Batman");
        _Movie.add("Superman");
        _Movie.add("Wonder Woman");
        _Movie.add("The Avengers");
    }
}
```

Here's the result I get:

Which movie would you like to see?
Wonder Woman
You entered Wonder woman movie
Sorry, we only have Batman, Superman, Wonder Woman, and The Avengers

Thanks for reading! 
*Edit* Sorry for the pictures. Didn't know it was a big deal on here. :/

Comment: Edit your question and post your code there instead of an image so people can review and test your code.

Comment: Maybe something like "for each string in string.split on space, then toUpper."

Comment: I suggest having a look at the `split` function of String.

Comment: `Wonder Woman only get the first letter capitalized in the 1st word and not the 2nd` not possible unless you have some rules or mapping code which tells the code the wonder women is a single word

Comment: Why not another class? You should use util classes to reuse that piece of code. For your problem, use the WordUtils.capitalizeFully(String str) from apache commons text.

Comment: Thanks for down voting guys. Really makes me feel good about myself.

Comment: By the way, such a method might be called `initCaps`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the space as delimiter, You can make use of `StringBuffer` to convert the first letter of the words to uppercase.

```
public String toFirstCharUpperAll(String string){
     StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(string);
        for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++)
            if(i==0 || sb.charAt(i-1)==' ')//first letter to uppercase by default
                sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i)));
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you posted the code as text rather than an image, but heres my suggestion:

1. Split the sentence into words
2. Capitalize each word (same way you have in your code)
3. Rejoin the words into a sentence

Heres the java code:

```js
// split into words
String[] words = title.split(" ");

// capitalize each word
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    words[i] = words[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

// rejoin back into a sentence
title = String.join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by a coworker:

```
var str = "test TEST"

// legacy deprecated version
str = org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils.capitalizeFully( str )

// current version
str = org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils.capitalizeFully( str )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).