# I wrote a code that sends the first character of a word to uppercase if a new word is starting in a sentence

Tags: java

Is there any simpler way to way to write this code?
I used space to solve the problem. Can we do it in another way?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chirag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        String input = obj.nextLine();
        int length = input.length();
        String a = "";
        int i;
        int n=input.indexOf(' ');
        for(i=0;i<length;i++) {

            char x = input.charAt(i);

            if(i==0) {
                x = Character.toUpperCase(x);
            }
            if(x==' ') {
                n=input.indexOf(x,i-1);
            }
            if(i==n+1) {
                x = Character.toUpperCase(x);
            }
            a += x;
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize first letter of each word in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688459/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-java)

Comment: @VaibhavSharma It does not seem to be the same problem, but related. It just needs to capitalize the next letter after space character followed by a period. It could be implemented using a regular expression like this: Find: `(\. \w)` Replace: `\U$1`